# Can jq handle nested JSON data?

Tags: python, json, jq

Maybe this is too much of a stretch for 'jq' and I need to jump into the python json module, but let's throw down a challenge for the gurus!!

I have some JSON data (from the i3 window manager) that looks a bit like this (simplified). I want to dig down through an arbitrary number of levels of .nodes/.floating_nodes and pull out .nodes or .floating_nodes that have "window" set to non-null. :

```
{
  "floating_nodes": [],
  "nodes": [
    {
      "floating_nodes": [],
      "nodes": [
        {
          "floating_nodes": [],
          "nodes": [
            {
              "floating_nodes": [],
              "nodes": [],
              "window": null,
              "name": "__i3_scratch",
            }
          ],
          "window": null,
          "name": "foobar",
        }
      ],
      "window": null,
      "name": "__i3",
    },
    {
      "floating_nodes": [],
      "nodes": [
        {
          "floating_nodes": [],
          "nodes": [],
          "window": null,
          "name": "topdock",
        },
        {
          "floating_nodes": [],
          "nodes": [
            {
              "floating_nodes": [],
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "floating_nodes": [],
                  "nodes": [],
                  "window": 8388613,
                  "name": "16:11 bhepple:.../~ — Konsole",
                  "rect": {
                    "height": 1061,
                    "width": 1920,
                    "y": 0,
                    "x": 0
                  },
              ],
              "window": null,
              "name": "1",
            }
          ],
          "window": null,
          "name": "content",
        },
        {
          "floating_nodes": [],
          "nodes": [
            {
              "floating_nodes": [],
              "nodes": [],
              "window": 14680070,
              "name": "i3bar for output VNC-0",
            }
          ],
          "window": null,
          "name": "bottomdock",
        }
      ],
      "window": null,
      "name": "VNC-0",
    }
  ],
  "window": null,
  "name": "root",
}
```

My sample JSON was a bit broken by my simplifications so here's the full version:

```
{"id":10883136,"type":"root","orientation":"horizontal","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":null,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"splith","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":1080},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"root","window":null,"nodes":[{"id":10883568,"type":"output","orientation":"none","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":0.5,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"output","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":1080},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"__i3","window":null,"nodes":[{"id":10884128,"type":"con","orientation":"horizontal","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":null,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"splith","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"content","window":null,"nodes":[{"id":10884720,"type":"workspace","orientation":"none","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":null,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"splith","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"__i3_scratch","num":-1,"window":null,"nodes":[],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[],"fullscreen_mode":1,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]}],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[10884720],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]}],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[10884128],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]},{"id":10886256,"type":"output","orientation":"none","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":0.5,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"output","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":1080},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"VNC-0","window":null,"nodes":[{"id":10886944,"type":"dockarea","orientation":"none","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":null,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"dockarea","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":0},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"topdock","window":null,"nodes":[],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[{"dock":2,"insert_where":2}]},{"id":10887648,"type":"con","orientation":"horizontal","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":null,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"splith","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":1061},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"content","window":null,"nodes":[{"id":10889056,"type":"workspace","orientation":"horizontal","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":null,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"splith","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":1061},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"1","num":1,"window":null,"nodes":[{"id":10895664,"type":"con","orientation":"none","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":1.0,"urgent":false,"focused":true,"layout":"splith","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":1061},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":1,"y":1,"width":1918,"height":1059},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":958,"height":1059},"name":"16:11 bhepple:.../~ — Konsole","window":8388613,"window_properties":{"class":"konsole","instance":"konsole","title":"16:11 bhepple:.../~ — Konsole","transient_for":null},"nodes":[],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]}],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[10895664],"fullscreen_mode":1,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]}],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[10889056],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]},{"id":10888352,"type":"dockarea","orientation":"none","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":null,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"dockarea","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":-1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":1061,"width":1920,"height":19},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"name":"bottomdock","window":null,"nodes":[{"id":10891392,"type":"con","orientation":"none","scratchpad_state":"none","percent":1.0,"urgent":false,"focused":false,"layout":"splith","workspace_layout":"default","last_split_layout":"splith","border":"pixel","current_border_width":1,"rect":{"x":0,"y":1061,"width":1920,"height":19},"deco_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0},"window_rect":{"x":0,"y":0,"width":1920,"height":19},"geometry":{"x":0,"y":1061,"width":3840,"height":19},"name":"i3bar for output VNC-0","window":14680070,"window_properties":{"class":"i3bar","instance":"i3bar","title":"i3bar for output VNC-0","transient_for":null},"nodes":[],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]}],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[10891392],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[{"dock":3,"insert_where":2}]}],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[10887648,10886944,10888352],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]}],"floating_nodes":[],"focus":[10886256,10883568],"fullscreen_mode":0,"sticky":false,"floating":"auto_off","swallows":[]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, jq can do this!

First, we use the recurse operator, `..`, to recursively iterate through everything. Then, we get all the `.nodes` and `.floating_nodes`, and we use `?` to ignore errors that would arise from trying to get properties from numbers, strings or objects. Then, we get all the elements in these arrays with `[]`. Again, ignoring the errors in the previous step left some `null`s, so we ignore the errors from trying to use `[]` on `null`s with a `?`. Lastly, we pipe everything to `select(.window != null)`, and we wrap every result in an array for easier treatment.

```
jq '[.. | .floating_nodes?, .nodes? | .[]? | select(.window != null)]'
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Trouble is, jq is throwing an error: 

`error: Invalid numeric literal (while parsing '..')
[.. | .floating_nodes?, .nodes? | .[]? | select(.window != null)]
 ^^
error: Invalid character
`
My jq is version 1.3

Comment: I would recommend getting jq 1.5 for this. If not, `..` should be defined as `recurse` on earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

If the `window` property can only appear on `node` or `floating_node` objects, you could simplify things by just searching for all objects that have `window` properties.

```
.. | objects | select(.window != null)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Trouble is, jq is throwing an error: 

    error: objects is not defined
    . | objects | select(.window != null)
        ^^^^^^^
    1 compile error
My jq is version 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Working off Santiago's solution and trying to backfill for what may be lacking in jq-1.3 I got this to work:

```
jq 'recurse(.[]) | .floating_nodes, .nodes | .[] | select(.window != null) | select(.focused == true) | .name'
```

... it also gave lots of error messages such as:

```
jq: error: Cannot iterate over number
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
jq: error: Cannot index number with string
```

Answer (score 0):

The following has been tested with jq 1.3, 1.4, and 1.5:

```
recurse(if type == "object" or type == "array" then .[] else empty end)
| select(type == "object")
| ( select(.nodes|type == "array") | .nodes[]),
  ( select(.floating_nodes|type == "array") | .floating_nodes[])
| select( .window != null )
```

Using the "full version" of the given input, jq 1.3 produces the following output:

```
{
  "swallows": [],
  "floating": "auto_off",
  "sticky": false,
  "fullscreen_mode": 0,
  "focus": [],
  "floating_nodes": [],
  "nodes": [],
  "window_properties": {
    "transient_for": null,
    "title": "16:11 bhepple:.../~ — Konsole",
    "instance": "konsole",
    "class": "konsole"
  },
  "window": 8388613,
  "name": "16:11 bhepple:.../~ — Konsole",
  "layout": "splith",
  "focused": true,
  "urgent": false,
  "percent": 1,
  "scratchpad_state": "none",
  "orientation": "none",
  "type": "con",
  "id": 10895664,
  "workspace_layout": "default",
  "last_split_layout": "splith",
  "border": "pixel",
  "current_border_width": 1,
  "rect": {
    "height": 1061,
    "width": 1920,
    "y": 0,
    "x": 0
  },
  "deco_rect": {
    "height": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "x": 0
  },
  "window_rect": {
    "height": 1059,
    "width": 1918,
    "y": 1,
    "x": 1
  },
  "geometry": {
    "height": 1059,
    "width": 958,
    "y": 0,
    "x": 0
  }
}
{
  "swallows": [],
  "floating": "auto_off",
  "sticky": false,
  "fullscreen_mode": 0,
  "focus": [],
  "floating_nodes": [],
  "nodes": [],
  "window_properties": {
    "transient_for": null,
    "title": "i3bar for output VNC-0",
    "instance": "i3bar",
    "class": "i3bar"
  },
  "window": 14680070,
  "name": "i3bar for output VNC-0",
  "layout": "splith",
  "focused": false,
  "urgent": false,
  "percent": 1,
  "scratchpad_state": "none",
  "orientation": "none",
  "type": "con",
  "id": 10891392,
  "workspace_layout": "default",
  "last_split_layout": "splith",
  "border": "pixel",
  "current_border_width": 1,
  "rect": {
    "height": 19,
    "width": 1920,
    "y": 1061,
    "x": 0
  },
  "deco_rect": {
    "height": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "x": 0
  },
  "window_rect": {
    "height": 19,
    "width": 1920,
    "y": 0,
    "x": 0
  },
  "geometry": {
    "height": 19,
    "width": 3840,
    "y": 1061,
    "x": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **tostream** to scan a stream of [path,value] arrays from the given input.  It then uses **select** to pick out only paths ending in "window" and whose corresponding value is not null.  Finally it uses **foreach** and **getpath** to produce a stream of the containing objects.

```
foreach (   tostream
          | select(length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "window" and .[1] != null)
        ) as $p (
    .
  ; .
  ; getpath($p[0][:-1])
)
```

EDIT: I now realize a filter of the form `foreach E as $X (.; .; R)` can almost always be rewritten as `E as $X | R` so the above is really just

```
  ( tostream | select(length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "window" and .[1] != null) ) as $p
|  getpath($p[0][:-1])
```

Comment: Gives a syntax error with jq-1.5:

`~/ $ i3-msg -t get_tree | jq 'foreach (   tostream
          | select(length == 2 and .[0][-1] == "window" and .[1] != null)
        ) as $p (
    .
  ; .
  ; getpath($p[0][:-1])'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 6:
  ; getpath($p[0][:-1])                      
jq: 1 compile error`

Comment: Looks like you need one more ) before the final '.